# Shading Becomes Darker With Animated Bevel Geometry on a Curve

Tags: animation, shaders, bezier-curves, bevel

The blue part is a bezier curve with bevel geometry turned on. When I animated the *End* property, mid-way the shader abruptly goes dark for a few frames.

[image]

The curve only has 4 control points.
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding a note here.

Your shading changes ***because*** your curve has only 4 control-points.

Smooth shading approximates smooth mid-face normals, and the transition of normals across hard geometric edges, by linearly interpolating across (render-triangulated) faces between vertex normals.

If your ink is vertically subdivided enough, then the linear approximation doesn't stray much from the actual normals of  the underlying geometry. (Only the length of the arrow on the left, below) The 'smoothness' extends only as far as you would expect it to, on this shape. With insufficient subdivision, as on the right, the normal interpolation is across the entire height of the column, 'curving' its surface in that dimension.

[image]

It makes the difference shown below:

[image]

If you want smooth-shading, the fixes would be to increase the U-resolution of your curve, in its 'Data' tab, 'Shape' panel, and to introduce control-points just above and below the sharp changes in radius.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robin, yes that was exactly the case. You have helped me twice in 2 days now. :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you notice the change in color happens precisely at the point in time when the bevel factor reaches the vertex with a different radius that changes thickness of the bevel.

This creates additional faces that are non coplanar with the previous extrusion body.
Since you object is shaded as *Smooth* Blender now starts to try to smooth the shading of the lateral faces with faces that are at start almost perpendicular to them, resulting changes in color.

To avoid this you may add an *Edge Split* modifier to your object to break the shading at the concave edge.

[image]

Since the angle is quite shallow you may need to adjust the *Split Angle* to a value small enough that matches thickness change but doesn't affect smoothing of the cylindrical part. If the two angles are two close, consider increasing the bevel resolution to a higher number.

Comment: I've been racking my head over this for 2 days. Thanks a lot. I now understand what's happening so I can try and counter it.